# How can I find interesting news sources to add to Gnus?

Tags: gnus

I recently transitioned to Gnus to read and write mail and I thought since Gnus is primarily a news reader I might as well also use it as such. But in all the tutorials I looked at I never found any actual suggestions for news sources to add to it, only technical details about how to do it. So where can I find interesting news sources to add to Gnus? From what I understand you can't just add arbitrary news sites to it, right? But  I also read about some people who use it to read most of the internet they are interested in. How can one do that?

Comment: "Interesting" is a matter of opinion. Please rewrite your question so that factual answers can be given. E.g. "how do I set up Gnus with a news feed of all the GNU news groups?" is such a question. If you have already set up *some* news feeds and are really looking for other news feeds on particular interests, then asking on Reddit is probably your best bet. But even there, you should specify what is "interesting".

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally your ISP would provide you with a news server to connect to (via NNTP). That news server would mirror many news groups, such as `comp.lang.lisp` or `alt.religion.emacs`. You would use Gnus to subscribe to the list of news groups that you found interesting, and to read new news as it arrived.

These days it is rare for an ISP to provide access to a news server. You might find a subscription news service is necessary instead.

Comment: `news.gmane.io` provides NNTP access to a bunch of GNU mailing lists, as well as the `comp.*` hierarchy and many others.